# How to delete the MBR (Master boot record) out of an image file?

Tags: linux, qemu, dd

I have a QEMU image `myserver.img` that is about 20GiB. The file serves as a "virtual" hard disk for the server. Now the first 512 bytes contain the MBR, and I am trying to overwrite those bytes with zeroes. On a normal disks, this one would work:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

But when I try that on the image file, the file gets overwritten and is only 512 bytes in size (instead of 20GiB). Is there a way to change only the first 512 bytes, preferably with `dd`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `conv=notrunc`:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=YOUR_IMAGE_FILE bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

Answer (score 7):

Try using dd with `conv=notrunc`

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=myserver.img bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

From the dd man page

```
   notrunc
          do not truncate the output file
```

e.g.

```
ls -l myserver.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 iain users 1536 Mar 27 12:31 myserver.img

dd if=/dev/zero of=myserver.img bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc

ls -l myserver.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 iain users 1536 Mar 27 12:32 myserver.img
```